# Footer Widgets not lining up in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have created a child theme of Twenty Thirteen and am doing some updates to it. I have a dev site that is pretty much a copy of the live site. The only thing that I changed in the footer area is the widget title styles but I can't get the 3 widgets to line up. I currently have 2 on the first line and 1 down below. It doesn't seem to matter if I change the container width.

Here is the new version of the site: http://dev.unitedconstruction.com/

Here is the old site that still works:http://unitedconstruction.com/

Can anyone see where my problem is?

CSS (most of what pertains to the footer)

```
/* FOOTER */
.site-footer .sidebar-container, .site-footer { 
    background-color: #fff; /*#C6C6C7;*/
}

.site-footer .sidebar-container {
    min-height: 335px;
    padding: 20px 0 0;
    border-top: 0 solid #0069AA;
}

.site-footer .widget{
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: 333px !important;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #0069AA;
    background-color: #fff;
    min-height: 358px;
    float:left;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 0 24px;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    color: #333;
}


.widget .widget-title {
    font: normal 24px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

.site-footer .widget-title, .site-footer .widget-title a, .site-footer .wp-caption-text {
    font: normal 24px 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-bottom:2px solid #FDFDFD;
    word-spacing:0;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.site-footer .widget-title span{
    color: #000;
    font-weight:normal;
}
.site-footer .widget li {
    padding:0 0 10px;
}
```

HTML

```
<footer role="contentinfo" class="site-footer" id="colophon">
                <div role="complementary" class="sidebar-container" id="secondary">
        <div class="widget-area masonry" style="position: relative; height: 399px;">
            <aside class="widget widget_flexible-recent-posts-widget masonry-brick" id="flexible-recent-posts-widget-3" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><div class="frp-widget-wrapper frp-widget-">
        <div class="frp-clear"></div>
    <ul class="frp-widget">
                <li class="frp-news">
            <h3 class="widget-title"><span>united</span> news</h3>
<div class="frp-clear"></div>
<div class="frp-left">
    <a href="http://unitedconstruction.com/united-celebrates-groundbreaking-for-new-1-6-million-sf-business-park/"><img width="333" height="200" alt="United Construction" class="attachment-333x333 wp-post-image" src="http://unitedconstruction.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/featured-image-Phase-II-Groundbreaking.jpg"></a>
</div>
<div class="news-widget-info">
<div class="news-widget-title">
        <a class="news-widget-link" href="http://unitedconstruction.com/united-celebrates-groundbreaking-for-new-1-6-million-sf-business-park/">United Celebrates Groundbreaking for New 1.6 Million SF Industrial Park</a>
    </div>
<div class="arpw-summary">UC breaks ground on new industrial park in North Reno. The first tenant, Jarden Technical Apparel, consisting of Marmot and ExOfficio, is pre-leasing 270,000 SF</div>
</div>
<div class="frp-clear"></div>
        </li>
            </ul>
        <div class="frp-all-category-news frp-all-category-news-footer"><a href="?page_id=7">read more &gt;&gt;</a></div>
    </div>
</aside><aside class="widget arpw_widget random-posts masonry-brick" id="arpw_widget-2" style="position: absolute; left: 353px; top: 0px;">

<h3 class="widget-title"><span>united</span> projects</h3>
                <div class="arpw-block">

                    <ul>


                            <li class="arpw-clearfix">


                                    <a rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to Lake Washington Partners &ndash; SanMar Distribution Center" href="http://unitedconstruction.com/otw-portfolio/lake-washington-partners-sanmar-distribution-center-showroom/">
                                        <img width="333" height="200" title="Lake Washington Partners &ndash; SanMar Distribution Center" alt="Lake Washington Partners &ndash; SanMar Distribution Center" class="arpw-alignleft wp-post-image" src="http://unitedconstruction.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/featured-image-sanmar.jpg">                                  </a>


                                <h3 class="arpw-title">
                                    <a rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to Lake Washington Partners &ndash; SanMar Distribution Center" href="http://unitedconstruction.com/otw-portfolio/lake-washington-partners-sanmar-distribution-center-showroom/">Lake Washington Partners &ndash; SanMar Distribution Center</a>
                                </h3>


                                                                    <div class="arpw-summary">621,738 SFt build-to-suit distribution center features automated…</div>

                            </li>


                    </ul>
            <div class="frp-all-category-news frp-all-category-news-footer">                <a title="See More United Construction Projects" href="?page_id=32">read more &gt;&gt;</a>          </div>
                </div><!-- .arpw-block - http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-random-posts-widget/ -->

            </aside><aside class="widget widget_flexible-recent-posts-widget masonry-brick" id="flexible-recent-posts-widget-2" style="position: absolute; left: 706px; top: 0px;"><div class="frp-widget-wrapper frp-widget-">
        <div class="frp-clear"></div>
    <ul class="frp-widget">
                <li class="frp-news">
            <h3 class="widget-title"><span>united</span> community</h3>
<div class="frp-clear"></div>
<div class="frp-left">
    <a href="http://unitedconstruction.com/honored-by-step2-recognition/"><img width="333" height="200" alt="Thank You STEP2" class="attachment-333x333 wp-post-image" src="http://unitedconstruction.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/featured-image-STEP2-Thank-you.jpg"></a>
</div>
<div class="news-widget-info">
<div class="news-widget-title">
        <a class="news-widget-link" href="http://unitedconstruction.com/honored-by-step2-recognition/">Honored by STEP2 Recognition</a>
    </div>
<div class="arpw-summary">United Construction is honored by STEP2's acknowledgement during the recent Homes For The Holiday event.</div>
</div>
<div class="frp-clear"></div>
        </li>
            </ul>
        <div class="frp-all-category-news frp-all-category-news-footer"><a href="http://unitedconstruction.com/in-the-community/">read more &gt;&gt;</a></div>
    </div>
</aside>        </div><!-- .widget-area -->
    </div><!-- #secondary -->

        </footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One major difference I'm noticing is that the height on your widget area div (`class="widget-area masonry"`) is different.

The broken site has div height of `height: 764px` while the functioning site has `height: 382px`.

This is giving the three divs room to stack ontop of each other.

Comment: Thanks! That reminded me that I had changed something in the twentythirteen functions. Just uploaded my old 2013 and it works!